# Get image path from database and display on the frontend (Octobercms)

Tags: php, database, model-view-controller, octobercms

this is my page

page.htm (Markup) - I manage to get the image name but I can't get the image source

```
<img id="avatar-image" alt="Jason's Image" src="{{ avatar_id }}"/>

{{ file_name }} // working       
{{ avatar_id }} // not working
```

page.htm(Code)

```
function onStart()
{
    $var = \System\Models\File::where("field", "=", "avatar")->first();
    $this["file_name"] = $var->file_name;
    $this["avatar_id"] = $var->path;
}
```

my model

model.php

```
class Settings extends Model
{
    public $implement = ['System.Behaviors.SettingsModel'];

    public $settingsCode = 'dca_plugins_settings';

    public $settingsFields = 'fields.yaml';

    public $attachOne = [ 'avatar' => ['System\Models\File'] ];
}
```

field.yaml

```
fields:
  id:
    label: ID
    disabled: true

  name:
    label: Image

  avatar:
    label: Avatar
    type: fileupload
    mode: image
    imageHeight: 150
    imageWidth: 250
```

can someone tell me how to get the path(image source)?

Answer (score 3):

Following the docs:

> The getPath() method returns the full URL of an uploaded public file.
>   The following code would print something like
>   ...mysite.com/uploads/public/path/to/avatar.jpg

In your case, would be something like:

```
$setting = Settings::first(); // Gets some settings model.
$avatar = $setting->avatar;
$avatarPath = null;

// Check if setting has an attached avatar.
if ($avatar) {
  $avatarPath = $avatar->getPath(); // Uploaded public file.
}
```

And inject into Twig environment via PHP Section, for example.

```
$this['avatar_path'] = $avatarPath;
```

Comment: This works perfectly when the image is defined as type `fileupload` and is stored by means of the integrated relation `System\Models\File`. What if the image is defined as type `mediafinder` and the value is stored as a string in the database? How would one find the path of it? I always get the error message `call to a member function getPath() on string`. Could you please advise?